# Put Date onto DatePicker From And To From JSON

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, angularjs, jquery-ui-datepicker

how can we put date taken from mySql db and converted to Javascript time.

I have an array of list with dates . i had been able to extract the dates like start and end date  but i need a way to put start date into date picker and to date picker.

time format is as

```
Wed Jan 01 2014 05:34:53 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

Comment: please post the code you tried yet

Comment: new Date()  is not working ?

Comment: AFAIK datepicker should accept that the input tag it is inserted in has a value attribute set. Use js to set that value and that's it!

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work for me. I presume your date string comes from a JSON input, but that's trivial....

```
var date = new Date("Wed Jan 01 2014 05:34:53 GMT+0530 (IST)");

$( "#mySelector" ).datepicker( "setDate", date );
```